# Can't access `<VoiceChannel>.members` or `<VoiceChannel>.full` properties

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to check wether or not a `<VoiceChannel>` has X amount of members in it. I tried using `<VoiceChannel>.members.size` but it always returns 0 even though I am connected to the voice channel. I tried logging the `<VoiceChannel>` object and it does not show the `#full` and `#members` properties. I have `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent declared and enabled in the developer portal.

I would also gladly accept as answer to this question an alternative way to check for the number of members in a voice channel.

Comment: Do you have the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent?

Comment: @MrMythical Yep that was it! Thanks! Turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Done. I couldn’t provide a code example since I don’t know how you instantiated your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the voice channel members requires the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent. Make sure you include that intent and it should return the right amount of people in it.